# Perforce (P4V) not opening after deleting workspace folder

Tags: windows, perforce, p4v

I deleted a folder by accident and now P4V doesn't open, I can see it in my task manager and it sucks up a ton of resources but nothing happens. Force-quitting and restarting doesn't help.

Any idea how I can reset my p4 environment or something? I've tried reinstalling the app on Windows and that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already tried force-quitting P4V and/or rebooting, try that first.

Failing that, you can "reset" P4V by deleting the `.p4qt` folder, which should be in the same folder that Perforce is installed in.  That will delete all of its settings and the next time it comes up it should have a clean slate.

Alternatively, you could try using the command line to restore the folder -- running `p4 clean` on a manually deleted folder will restore it to its previously-synced state.

Comment: p4 clean command doesn't work and .p4qt doesn't exist.

Comment: You might be having a different problem from OP.  P4V always creates a `.p4qt` folder on install, and `p4 clean` should always work to restore a workspace folder you've deleted manually (unless you had the files open, in which case you want `p4 revert`).